# Software to recover corrupt JPEGs on CD-RW

Tags: optical-media, data-recovery

I just got back from a trip to Europe, was using my digital camera and downloading to a CD-RW at Internet cafes when the card got full.  I did it three times, the first two worked ok. The last one appeared to work ok (I was able to read the JPEGs off the CD after burning at the Internet cafe), but after bringing the disc home, I cannot read that last directory. I am not sure if the data is corrupt or the disc was somehow damaged. If the disc was damaged, I find it strange that only that directory is affected and the other 2 are perfectly ok. I tried to repair the disc with a kit I bought. It seemed to remove the scratches but the disc does not read any better. Some programs try to read each JPEG and just fail. Other programs, keep trying to read the JPEG, and sometimes get half of it, sometimes all of it, sometimes none. In this case, it takes a very long time to read each file (a few min). It almost seems like the program is repeteadly trying to the same sector when it fails to read it correctly the first time.

Is there a software that would help me recover images from the CD?

Comment: Why the votes to close? This is a perfectly cromulent question for this site. Especially given that thare are as many upvotes, declaring it a good question, as downvotes, with still no answers or comments.

Comment: I know this sounds too obvious - but, if the problem is with the last DVD, then are the photos still not in your camera?

Comment: I agree with @Mawg here: this definitely is ***not*** off-topic. It might lack some details (e.g. is the OS relevant and, if so, which must it be?), and might be a duplicate to [How to recover data from old DVD's?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20036/185) – but it's definitely and perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CD/DVD get scratched due to regular use. You can use following methods to recover data. I assure you that after using these methods, you will have all your data.

1. Clean the CD/DVD properly as dust can be a reason.
2. Use a CD/DVD writer instead a CD/DVD reader device for such corrupted disks, because DVD writer are more powerful than DVD reader.
3. If nothing happens, then you should opt for a third party data recovery software. This is the best way to recover data from CD/DVD/Blue-Ray disks.

You may also apply following instrument, in case guide on above doesn't work https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-to-recover-data-from-corrupted-cd-disk/26571

Comment: Could you please be a bit more detailed in step 3? As this site is about recommending software, that's the most relevant part here.

Answer (score 2):

It may well be  that you cannot recover 100% of your data.

I have had success, under similar circumstances, with [Unstoppable Copier](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29).

> Recovers files from disks with physical damage. Allows you to copy
>   files from disks with problems such as bad sectors, scratches or that
>   just give errors when reading data. The program will attempt to
>   recover every readable piece of a file and put the pieces together.
>   Using this method most types of files can be made useable even if some
>   parts of the file were not recoverable in the end.
>
> The program can be used as a daily backup system using its batch mode
>   functions. A list of transfers can be saved to a file and then run
>   from the command line to perform the same batch of transfers on a
>   regular basis without having to use the GUI interface. The program
>   supports command line parameters which allow the application to be run
>   from schedulers or scripts so it can be fully integrated into daily
>   server tasks

It is available for both Windows & Linux (you did not specify an o/s) and is free (you did not specify a budget).

It worked for me - here's hoping that it will work for you too.

---

See also:
 - http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-cd-recovery-utility.htm
 - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-repair-and-recover-data-from-damaged-cds-or-dvds/
 - http://www.recoverdisc.com/

If none of the above help and you really, really, ***really*** want your data back, you might have to pay for professional data recovery.